# Solr search - how to prevent duplicates from location hash

Tags: search, solr, lucene, nutch

I'm getting results back from a crawled internal site. The problem is I'm getting multiple results because of the use of location hashes in the code:

```
http://site.com/en/personal/refunds.html
http://site.com/en/personal/refunds.html#
http://site.com/en/personal/refunds.html#content
http://site.com/en/personal/refunds.html#section1
```

Although they may all be relevant, it doesn't look good when they're my top four results! 
Any way they can be seen as one result?

It looks like # and #content occur on most pages, so I could apply some rule to filter these out. They're used to skip to content and another to toggle accessibility stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got this working, what I did was edit the **regex-normalize.xml** file and told it to ignore URLs with # in them:

```
<regex>
  <pattern>#.*</pattern>
  <substitution>$1</substitution>
</regex>
```

I needed to add "urlfilter-regex" to the plugin.includes property in **nutch-site.xml** to get it to use this file.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the url ending with the pattern having # in them.
You can specify the patterns you want to include or exclude in [regex-urlfilter.txt](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt.template?view=markup)

This would allow only the root page to be indexed and the ones with # to be excluded from being indexed.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried editing this file but still getting the hashes. 
What I did was add it to this line:

`# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=#]`

Comment: OK I got this working, the problem was that it wasn't paying attention to my changes until I added urlfilter-regex to the plugin.includes property.

Answer (score 1):

The first option, and best option, is don't crawl any page of this kind. Using, as @Jayendra mentioned, the regex urlfilter

Another option you have is modifying indexed document values using the update chain feature. 
Implementing the interface [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequest) and parse it by yourself using Java code, modifying the URL to remove the #anchor element.

And the last option I have in mind is to use an [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) in the URL field as follows:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(#.*)" replacement=""/>
```

Using the first solution you only index one page per "location". Using the others you will index all pages, but only the last is really indexed as Solr will delete any previous version of this document.